# Привязка локального репозитория с Github

Tags: git, github

Решил разместить проект на Github. Создал новый репозиторий на Github без создания README.md, .gitignore и файла лицензии. Далее выполнил следующие действия в PyCharm.

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M master
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/project.git
git push -u origin master
```

Проект нормально скопировался на Github. Попробовал выполнить все тоже самое, но при создании репозитория на Github создал README.md, .gitignore. Возникла ошибка:

*-! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)*

*error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/user/project.git'*

*hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository
pushing to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the
remote changes (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for
details.*

Comment: а чего вы ожидали? у вас два репозитория с разными историями. естественно, сделать push из одного репозитория в другой у вас не выйдет. просто не создавайте коммит во втором репозитории (который на сервере github.com). т.е.: не делайте вот этого: «создал README.md, .gitignore»

Comment: Ожидал, что локальный и удаленный репозитории объединятся. Благодарю за ответ.

Comment: практически дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1197561/178576

Comment: Дубликат не может быть создан раньше...