# Слить ветку master и main

Tags: github, git-branch

Создал проект и главная была ветка master, сделал коммиты, запушил. Получается в ветке main лежит только .gitignore, а на компе видна только ветка master. Как их слить в main?

Comment: ничего не понятно. а) упоминаются три ветки: `master`, `Master`, `main`. откуда они все взялись? б) откуда взялся файл `.gitignore` в ветке `main`? в) что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: 1) ветки две: master, main
2) .gitignore создался при создании репрозитория через гитхаб. потом я через git init  и push свой репрозиторий запушил в тот. 
3) Не знаю как получить эту ветку main, чтобы слить ее с master

Comment: `$ git checkout main`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

если локальное хранилище у вас уже существовало, то ни к чему было создавать коммит на сервере github.com (об этом там явно написано: пропустите этот шаг, если локальное хранилище у вас уже есть). но будем исходить из предположения, что сгенерированное сервером содержимое файла `.gitignore` вам остро необходимо. это **допущение номер раз**.

следующая проблема, с которой вы столкнулись, проистекает из сумасбродства (моё оценочное суждение) владельцев сервера github.com — в то время как программа *git* создаёт по умолчанию ветку с именем `master`, не так давно они решили у себя на сервере создавать ветку с именем `main`. будем исходить из предположения, что вы согласны пойти у них на поводу и использовать имя `main` как локально, так и в копии вашего хранилища на их сервере. это **допущение номер два**.

---

итак, что у вас есть?

1. в локальном хранилище ветка `master` с одним или несколькими коммитами.
2. в хранилище на github.com ветка `main` с одним коммитом, в котором создан автоматически сгенерированный файл `.gitignore`.

что хотим получить?

1. локальное хранилище с веткой `main`, содержащее как коммиты из локальной ветки `master`, так и коммит, созданный в ветке `main` на сервере github.com
2. идентичную картину и в хранилище на сервере github.com

план действий:

1. если ещё не подключили к своему локальному хранилищу то хранилище, что создали на сервере, то подключите и заберите оттуда информацию:

   ```
   $ git remote add origin git@github.com:имя-вашей-учётной-записи/имя-хранилища
   $ git fetch --all
   ```
2. если вдруг текущей у вас объявлена не ветка `master`, то сделайте её таковой:

   ```
   $ git checkout master
   ```
3. добавьте в эту ветку коммит, созданный сервером в ветке `main` (содержащий создание автосгенерированного файла `.gitignore`):

   ```
   $ git cherry-pick origin/main
   ```
4. создайте локальную ветку `main`, которая будет указывать (ветка в git — это ведь просто плавающий указатель, верно?) на тот же коммит, что и `master`:

   ```
   $ git branch -f main master
   ```
5. теперь сделайте ветку `main` текущей:

   ```
   $ git checkout main
   ```
6. удалите ветку `master`:

   ```
   $ git branch -D master
   ```
7. и отправьте ветку `main` на сервер, делая одновременно и перезапись (опция `-f`) привязку локальной ветки к ветке на сервере (опция `-u`):

   ```
   $ git push -f -u origin main
   ```

на этом всё. доп. чтение:

- `$ man git-remote`
- `$ man git-fetch`
- `$ man git-checkout`
- `$ man git-cherry-pick`
- `$ man git-branch`
- `$ man git-push`

но в следующий раз постарайтесь не создавать самому себе проблемы на ровном месте: **либо** создавайте пустое хранилище на сервере и отправляйте в него содержимое своего локального хранилища, **либо**, раз создаёте непустое хранилище на сервере, сделайте его локальный клон, а в него уже добавляйте ваши коммиты.

Answer (score 2):

Столкнулся с такой же ситуацией, начал изучать Git на PyCharm.
Я решил её довольно просто, я удалил ветку 'master' из репозитория на github, затем переименовал main в master, после этого повторно запушил проект на github. При запросе подтвердил rebase.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1 вариант:

```
1. git pull repo_title main (скопировать содержимое удаленного репозитория в локальный)
2. git checkout master (переместиться в ветку master)
3. git merge main (скопировать содержимое с ветки main в ветку master)
4. git branch -d main (удалить ветку main)
5. git push repo_title master (обновить ветку master удаленного репозитория)
6. git push --delete repo_title main (удалить ветку main на удаленном репозитории)
```

2 вариант: скопировать файл `.gitignore` в локальный репозиторий. Удалить ветку `main` (п. 6 либо удалить в интерфейсе Github).

Comment: пишет при первой команде выдает refusing to merge unrelated histories.  в гите тоже когда заходишь в ветке во вкладку merge and pull reqest пишет: There isn’t anything to compare.
main and master are entirely different commit histories.